# How to convert a rdd of pandas DataFrame to Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I create a rdd of pandas DataFrame as intermediate result. I want to convert  a Spark DataFrame, eventually save it into parquet file.

I want to know what is the efficient way.

Thanks

```
def create_df(x):
  return pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 3)).\
           assign(col=x)

sc.parallelize(range(5)).map(create_df).\
          .TO_DATAFRAME()..write.format("parquet").save("parquet_file")
```

I have tried pd.concat to reduce rdd to a big dataframe, seems not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

def create_df(x): 
    df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 3)).assign(col=x)
    return df.values.tolist()


sc.parallelize(range(5)).flatMap(create_df).toDF().\
.write.format("parquet").save("parquet_file")
```

Answer (score 0):

So talking of efficiency, since spark 2.3 Apache Arrow is integrated with Spark and it is supposed to efficiently transfer data between JVM and Python processes thus enhancing the performance of the conversion from pandas dataframe to spark dataframe. You can enable it by

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
```

If your spark distribution doesn't have arrow integrated, this should not throw an error, will just be ignored.

A sample code to be run at pyspark shell can be like below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
pdf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 3))
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
df.write.format("parquet").save('data_parquet_file')
```

Comment: Thanks. create_df creates a pd.DataFrame. sc.parallelize(range(5)).map(create_df) gives a rdd of pd.DataFrame. Then how to create a spark.DF from this rdd?

Answer (score 0):

Your create_df method returns a panda dataframe and from that you can create spark dataframe - not sure why you need "sc.parallelize(range(5)).map(create_df)"

So your full code can be like

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
def create_df(x): 
    return pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 3)).assign(col=x) 


pdf = create_df(10) 
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf) 
df.write.format("parquet").save('data_parquet_file')
```

Comment: Thanks. My create_df is an external function which return a pandas dataframe, could be complicated, depending on perameters of x (could be complicated too). my number of x could be big, that is why I need to parallelize it.